# Recursively find the largest number in an integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am required to find the largest number in an integer array recursively. My function crashed but I cannot find the bug. Here's my c++ code:

```
void Numbers::compare(int size)
{
if(size == 0)
    cout << "You must enter an number!" << endl;

if(size ==1)
    cout << "The max number is " <<  numArray[0] << endl;

if(size >1)
{
    if(numArray[size-1] > numArray[size-2])
    {
        int temp = 0;
        numArray[size-1] = temp;
        temp = numArray[size-2];
        numArray[size-2]= numArray[size-1];
        size --;

    }
  size = size -1 ;
  compare(size);

}


}
```

Comment: What's the error reported when it crashes?

Comment: It seems that I accidentally set up the breakpoint. I just cleared it, and now it could be compiled correctly. However, it won't give me the correct answer. It always gives me the the numArray[0].

Answer (score 0):

here is a problem:

```
    int temp = 0; 
    numArray[size-1] = temp; // set numArray[size-1]=0
    temp = numArray[size-2];
    numArray[size-2]= numArray[size-1];// set numArray[size-2]= 0
    size --;
```

you set the entire array to be 0.

what you meant to do:

```
    int temp = numArray[size-2]; 
    numArray[size-2] = numArray[size-1];
    numArray[size-1]= temp
    size --;
```

Note that you change the array in the process, not sure if that is what you meant to do.

Comment: Yeah, I think you pointed out the problem, but your code didn't fix the problem. It keeps on giving me the first number of the array.

Comment: I just did another test. The problem is: it will never go into if (size > 1). So it either gives me the numArray[0] or the number doesn't exist. But I don't know why it won't go in.